# Why is this timing out well before 30 minutes?

Tags: vbscript, odbc, adodb, intersystems-cache

Here is my code for opening a database connection and doing a query

```
Set dbo = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbo.CommandTimeout = 1800
dbo.ConnectionTimeout = 1800
dbo.Open(DSN)
Set results = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
results.open SQL, DSN
if results.eof then 
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "No records found."
else
    stuff happens here
end if
```

For some reason it keeps timing out after 30 seconds regardless of having set both CommandTimeout and ConnectionTimeout on the connection.

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [Cache ODBC][State :
>   S1T00][N ative Code 450]

I don't see any `timeout` property on [the `ADODB.Recordset` object.](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_recordset.asp)

Comment: It's provider dependent and is set via the `.Properties` collection. It's likely using a Caché DB default timeout value see [Using Caché as an ODBC Data Source on Windows](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens201513/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BGOD_winodbc)

Comment: There does appear to be a setting you can override `Disable Query Timeout` - See [Caché ODBC/JDBC User's Guide - Connecting via ODBC](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache41/dbc/dbcoconnect.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the setting below.  It's not ideal, but at at least my long-running queries run, even if they take days.

[image]